# Why isn't there a simpler find function for associative std containers

Tags: c++, coding-style, dictionary, set, std

Why isn't there a 'find' function in associative std containers (map, set, etc) that returns a boolean?

Say:

```
std::map <int,int> mMap;
...
if ( mMap.contains(75) ) ...
```

I know about the find() and that I can do it this way

```
if ( mMap.find(75) != mMap.end() ) ...
```

But I feel it clutters the code more than anything else.

Why isn't there a simpler function for this, I mean containers are quite much about finding things in them?

Comment: As usual, no problem with downvotes but please do tell why. You know, no punishment without educational value ;-)

Comment: [`std::map::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) will do what you want.

Comment: Close enough to make an answer (if you post it I'll accept it)!

Comment: @Valmond: because "why" questions about library API design often are a matter of debate, rather than having a correct answer. If you instead want to know "how" (which KillianDS's comment addresses), re-write your question and I'll happily vote to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own (note, it's "HasKey" because "Contains" would deal with values)

```
template <class AssocContainer>
bool HasKey(const AssocContainer& haystack,
    const typename AssocContainer::key_type& needle)
{
    return haystack.find(needle) != haystack.end();
}

map<int, int> m;
m[0] = 1;
bool b = HasKey(m, 0);
```

Comment: Yes that will work +1 but that will clutter up a bit too.

Answer (score 3):

One simple reason is that it is useless (and makes you more inefficient).

Think about it this way, when you say:

```
mMap.find(75)
```

you are searching for `75`, but for what? You want to use it later!

So why write `if (mMap.find(75) != mMap.end())` and then later again find `75` to use it?

You can write:

```
std::map<int, int> mMap;
std::map<int, int>::iterator whatIWant = mMap.find(75);
if (whatIWant != mMap.end())
{
    int mapsTo = whatIWant->second;
    ...
}
```

This means that you issue `find` once and you get the result of both `contains` and the actual node in the map.

Comment: Yes I thought about that but it isn't always the case, sometimes I need to check if the value is there before using mMap[57].foo=1; so I don't accidentally creates a new entry. BTW are you sure things like that doesn't get optimized by the compiler nowadays?

Comment: @Valmond - the case you list is precisely the case that Shahbaz is describing. Replace your expression with `whatIWant.second.foo = 1`. This will avoid the redundant lookup.

Comment: There are plenty of use cases where you just want to know if it is there and not do anything else with it.

Comment: Okay, I should have put it the other way around I guess (insert if not existing, maybe that could work as an example), but sometimes you just want to know if the data is there, not doing anything with it, hence the question.

Comment: @Valmond and @visitor, you are right, sometimes you do need such a thing. I personally have many places where I have used this myself. I never thought of it as ugly though. I mean, at the very least, checking for existence of a key is always `" != mMap.end()"`, which is uniform everywhere as opposed to sometimes this and sometimes that.

Comment: Perhaps what would be more interesting (and more general) would be for iterators to cast to `bool`, indicating whether they point to a valid object or not. So all the `!= whatever.end()`s (like in `for`s or your case) could be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer is that the find function has 2 responsibilities in this case you can use the same code in order to do two different things find something and check if it exist so less code less bugs as usual.